# Jetpack compose: Bug with Textfield extract mode

Tags: android, kotlin, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an Android application with Jetpack compose, and I noticed that on screens with little vertical space, the textfield components switch to "full screen" over the keyboard ([extract mode](https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/801175/Disabling-the-fullscreen-editing-view-for-soft-keyboard-input-in-landscape)).

So far the behavior is normal, however the weird behavior appears when trying to enter text in the input field in extract mode, the typed characters **are not displayed**. However, once we close the keyboard and the text field returns to its classic form the typed text appears.

[Find here a video showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJZwB.gif) and the corresponding code:

```kotlin
val emailField: MutableState<String> = remember { mutableStateOf("Hi stackoverflow") }

Column(Modifier.padding(12.dp)) {
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = emailField.value,
        onValueChange = {
            emailField.value = it
        },
        singleLine = true,
        isError = emailError,
        leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Email, contentDescription = "") },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onNext = {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        ),
        label = {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.settings_authenticate_email_address))
        }
    )
}
```

Could this be a bug in Jetpack compose, or a problem with the code itself?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I do not see a bug filed that is related to this, and I do not see how your code could cause this effect. I recommend that you simplify your sample as far as is reasonable, such as removing `leadingIcon`, `keyboardOptions`, and `keyboardActions`, and confirm that you still see the effect. Then, file a bug report with the same sorts of evidence that you supplied here. The Compose team is above-Google-average with respect to responding to bug reports, so there is a decent chance that your report will get looked at and evaluated.

Comment: I simplified the code as much as possible but unfortunately the bug is still present.
I created a [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204209058)
I will see if the problem is addressed